# Xamarin Forms - Append labels to BoxView using C#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I would like to append labels to a box view using C#. The labels have to correspond to certain columns within each row.

The labels should fill the columns under the headers as in the picture below:

[image]

However after appending the the content to the Grid element it becomes a jumbled mess. Below is my code

.xaml

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
      <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <!-- Vertical Lines -->
  <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="7" />
  <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="7" />
  <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="7" />
  <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Grid.RowSpan="7" />
  <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="8" Grid.RowSpan="7" />
  <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" Grid.RowSpan="7" />
  <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="12" Grid.RowSpan="7" />
  <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="14" Grid.RowSpan="7" />

<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="14" Text="Title" Style="{StaticResource headerRowStyle}"  />
<BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="14" />
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Head 1" Style="{StaticResource resultTypeRow}" />
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="Head 2" Style="{StaticResource resultTypeRow}" />
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Text="Head 3" Style="{StaticResource resultTypeRow}" />
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="7" Text="Head 4" Style="{StaticResource resultTypeRow}" />
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="9" Text="Head 5" Style="{StaticResource resultTypeRow}" />
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="11" Text="Head 6" Style="{StaticResource resultTypeRow}" />
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="13" Text="Head 7" Style="{StaticResource resultTypeRow}" />
</Grid>
```

data.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
     base.OnAppearing();
     var row = 3;
     foreach (var result in Results)
     {
           var dist = new Label
           {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                FontSize = 9,
                Text = result.Dist.ToString(),
            };
            var cycle = new Label
            {
                 HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                 VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                 FontSize = 9,
                 Text = result.cycle.ToString(),
            };
            //REST OF LABELS HERE THEN APPEND TO PANEL 
            //Panel is the x:Name of the Grid Element

            Panel.Children.Add(dist,1,row);
            Panel.Children.Add(cycle, 3, row);
            Panel.Children.Add(data, 5, row);
            Panel.Children.Add(data2, 7, row);
            Panel.Children.Add(data3, 9, row);
            Panel.Children.Add(data4, 11, row);
            Panel.Children.Add(data5, 13, row);
            row++;
            count++;
     }
 }
```

> **Any idea what I need to do be able to neatly fit my results into those columns?**

Comment: A boxview can only have one children, create a boxview, add to it a stackpanel and add the labels to the stackpanel

Comment: So create a stack layout, add the labels to the stack layout with the appropriate width sizes, and append to the row definition?

Comment: Create a boxview, add a stacklayout and add to the stacklayout the labels. Also, use FillAndExpand on all the controls to fill all the space on the cells.